# How to Flatmap collection inside Pair in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, higher-order-functions, flatmap

In this example I have to classes.

```
Order(selections: List<Selection>, discount: Double, ...)
Selection(productId: Long, price: Double, ...)
```

I then keep collection of `Order` that I want to calculate prices afterward which need to use `Selection's price` and `Order's discount`. How can I do this?

I try to do the following but it doesn't seem to be possible.

```
val orderList: List<Order> = loadFromDB()

orderList.map { Pair(it.selections, it.discount) }  
.flatMap { /* Here I want to get list of Pair of selection from all orders with discount. */}
```

Once I have Collection of `Pair(Selection, discount)` then I can continue calculating further.
Is that possible to do in this form? Do I need to separate the chain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get a list of Pairs you can do the following:

```
orderList.flatMap { order -> //flatMap joins multiple lists together into one
    order.selections.map { selection ->    //Map every selection into a Pair<Selection, Discount>
        Pair(selection, order.discount) }
    .map { pair -> /* Do your stuff here */ }
```

Comment: Seems like I literally was not thinking big enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate syntax to @D3xter's answer using a bit more Kotlin sugar:

```
1    orderList
2        .flatMap { order ->
3            order.selections.map { selection ->
4                order.discount to selection.price } 
5        .map { (discount, price) -> ... }
```

This makes use of two Kotlin features:

1. [to](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to.html) infix operator on line 4 which is a "factory function" for `Pair`
2. [Destructuring](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html) the pair on line 5 directly into named variables `discount` and `price`